# Can't access http page on Azure VM

Tags: http, azure, remote-connection

I create an Ubuntu VM on Azure. By default in the inbound rules there was only the rule the maps from `*` to `22`.

I changed the rule to `22` to `22` (changed the `*` to `22`) and added a rule from `80` to `80`.

Problem is - I can't access an HTTP server that's on the machine. I tried to run `wget http://localhost` and I got the correct `index.html` page. But, when I try to run it form outside, it doesn't work.

Comment: Try to run it from outside means?

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to access this using your instance's IP(DIP). You need to access this using your Cloud Service's VIP  which you can obtain from your instance's dashboard in Azure portal. Your final command will look like -

```
wget http://CloudServiceVIP
```